# DateTime to XML format but keep the datatype as datetime

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datetime

I have a datetime with the normal .Net format (dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM). Now, I want to convert it to

xml datetime format (1999-05-31T13:20:00-05:00).

I am able to do in few ways
somedate is a datetime type variable

```
string formatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz";
string datestring = somedate.ToString(formatString);
```

but then the datatype of the xml changes to string. How can I change to xml format and keep the data type as datetime. How to convert datestring to the datatype datetime but keep the xml format

Comment: It seems to me you're misunderstanding how the datetime is being stored.

Comment: Can you show how you generate XML?

Comment: `datetime`s don't *have* a format.

Answer (score 0):

The dateTime object holds the date and time in a way that is independent of any formatting. The output format is chosen when you convert the value to a string. If it comes out as dd:mm:yyyy, that's because it's defaulting to the format used by the country/language configured for your machine. So the answer is, if you want the ISO format (which you refer to as XML format), then the time to request this is at the time you output the dateTime as XML; it's not a property of the date/time value itself.